# How do I properly export a .jar file with IntelliJ?

Tags: plugins, jar, intellij-idea

I get that I have to use the Build Artifact option, and include all of those module files, but whenever I build the artifact, the ONLY thing that is in the .jar is the manifest file. How do i get the rest of my program into the .jar?

Answer (score 1):

You should click the '+' and add 'Module output' to jar file.

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. [Here is that screen](http://puu.sh/3fxEh.png) and [Here is what's inside the .jar file](http://puu.sh/3fxFH.png)

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your project. You could try to recreate a project or module.